# How to solve the Two doorway and one camera problem?

Tags: algorithm, queue, stack

Consider a room with two doorways and a video camera that observes people entering and exiting via only one of the doorways. Describe an algorithmic approach to recognize whether individuals exiting via the camera doorway had entered via the same doorway earlier. How would you develop it to ensure robust performance?

I am guessing it could be solved by stack or queue.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: *"the camera doorway"*: is there a distinction between a *camera doorway* and a *non-camera doorway*?

Comment: What should the algorithm actually do? Count the number of people that enter and exit through the same door? Name them? How is the input organised? Is it given at time intervals, or is the input given at once? ...etc. This question needs to be more specific. Secondly, you should add your attempt at solving it, and describe where you hit a problem (wrong output? error? infinite loop?). Provide an example of input and expected output.

Comment: I don't see how a stack or queue would help since people can leave in an arbitrary order relative to entering. Why not just a hash-set keyed by person that records whether they entered through the observed door and checks that when they leave through it?

Comment: Side note: if it's a single camera you would have to associate a back view of an exiting person with their front (face) view to 'recognize' the person. Oh, and one funny situation to consider: suppose someone is exiting the room and turns head to look backwards. Just because someone said something interesting. You would have to not confuse a view of the face with an action of entering the room....

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

- Make a hash map of people entering at the camera door.
- Register them.
- if a person exits the camera door check the register to see if they entered the same door.
- remove exiting persons from the register.

Pseudo code

```
dict entered = {}

on enter:
  entered.add(person)

on exit:
  if entered.find(person)
    print "Person entered and exited at the same door"
    entered.remove(person)
```

So if the person enters twice on the camera door they are only registered once because they must have exited on the other door.

Caveat if a person enters the camera door, exits the other door, and then re-enters the other door and goes out the camera door it will register as if he entered and exited the camera door.